# Redirect to /login for unauthenticated users

Tags: authentication, clojure, compojure, ring, luminus

I'm trying to get a good handle on auth for compojure, ring apps.  What I want to do is redirect to `/login` if the user is not authenticated.  The below approach seems to be doing what I want.

I added the `wrap-restricted` handler to my `#'home-routes` like here:

```
(def app-routes
  (routes
   (-> #'home-routes
       (wrap-routes middleware/wrap-restricted)
       (wrap-routes middleware/wrap-csrf)
       (wrap-routes middleware/wrap-formats)
       ...))
```

Then in middleware I changed the `on-error`, which is referred to in the `wrap-restricted` handler, to do the redirect instead of 403 response:

```
(defn on-error [request response]
  ;; (error-page
  ;;   {:status 403
  ;;    :title (str "Access to " (:uri request) " is not authorized")})
  (redirect (format "/login?next=%s" (:uri request))))


(defn wrap-restricted [handler]
  (restrict handler {:handler authenticated?
                     :on-error on-error}))
```

My question is, is this the right (recommended best-practice) approach?

Comment: Did you try using authentication libraries, like https://github.com/cemerick/friend ?

Comment: @Aleph Aleph Yes. The code was generated with luminus, which comes with buddy.